# how do ssrs groups work?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to understand how ssrs formats the way data is presented. I have a table in ssms and a sp that gets the data from that table. The sp code is:

```
select *
from [CustData]
where 1 = 1
and (reportYear = @dbParam_reportYear or reportYear = @dbParam_reportYear-1 )
and marketCode=@dbParam_marketCode
and brandName=@dbParam_brandName
and (contactSegmentDesc=@dbParam_contactSegmentDesc)
order by reportYear ASC, reportMonth ASC
```

This obviously returns the data row by row i.e. if the report year param is 2014, then the rows with 2014 and then rows with 2013 data.

image:[image]

This is then used in ssrs in a report but the data is presented by columns. The column group is like `[segmentDesc] [reportMonth] [reportYear]` followed by all the data that is retrieved.

image: [image]

I need to know what is formatting the data output from row by row to column by column presentation. I do suspect its the column groups but need to confirm. I am new to this.

Getting difference of the values:

[image]

Comment: Search for SSRS Matrix

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207149.aspx

Comment: Typically the column groups let you create matrix while row groups are usually used to create tables. The column group in your image is like `Month` as parent group and `Year` as child group.

Answer (score 1):

This can be conducted with use of SSRS matrix. Here is a nice tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zERexbgCG5A

The delta can be calculated with the following approach: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e77d6526-cadc-4d14-8ca3-997d58cb7c4a/ssrs-matrix-difference-between-columns?forum=sqlreportingservices

Notice the following:

```
=(Code.GetMaxValue(RunningValue(Fields!Month.Value,CountDistinct,"Services"),(Fields!Amount.Value)-Previous(FIRST(Fields!Amount.Value))))
```

Comment: cheers, i ve watched that video a few times, i ll blame my memory for forgetting. Thanks!

Comment: wait, so would using exactly this allow me to calculate difference between 2 values of an attribute?

Comment: @Faiz. are you trying to fetch delta by Month/Year?

Comment: ya, i ll add an image on my question to show what i mean. in the vLY column can i get the difference of the values considering the way the sp is defined to get data?

Comment: @Faiz you can either address this in your query / stored procedure or try to get it done with matrix. As far as I remeber the matrix allows that, but I don't remember if I had a chance to try it once.

Comment: ah. i want it done in matrix i thought maybe if i figure out how data is shown by column level then i can do this but cant think of how to do it.

Comment: Yes, you can. Have a look: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e77d6526-cadc-4d14-8ca3-997d58cb7c4a/ssrs-matrix-difference-between-columns?forum=sqlreportingservices